# Error using parfor in matlab // The variable in a parfor cannot be classified

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have the following *for loop* **inside** a *parfor loop*:

```
for j1=1:NN
    for j2=1:NN
            HF(j1,j2)=hf(mod((j1-j2),NN)+1);  
     end
end
```

I get the error message saying:

> The variable HF in a parfor cannot be classified.

I do not use or define HF outside the parfor loop or anywhere else. Each iteration creates its own version of HF.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Suever I read that answer.. They are creating multiple copies of a matrix that exists. In my case HF is being created with different length/size in each parfor loop.

Comment: You will need to show more code to get better help. Do you actually initialize `HF` outside of the loop shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not initializing `HF` outside of the loop, when parsing your code, MATLAB thinks that you are modifying a *shared* variable `HF` from within the `parfor`. This is problematic because multiple workers can't modify the same data. This leads to the error that you are seeing.

To fix this, you need to explicitly pre-allocate `HF` outside of your loop to help MATLAB figure out that each iteration through the `parfor` loop is operating on a *different* `HF`.

```
HF = zeros(NN, NN);

for j1=1:NN
    for j2=1:NN
        HF(j1,j2)=hf(mod((j1-j2),NN)+1);  
    end
end
```